# React Native. How to get chars by Keyboard?

Tags: react-native

I want make code like this:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
   console.log(event)
})
```

How I can do it in React Native? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the chars values using the prop [`onKeyPress`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onkeypress) from `TextInput`. To get an event when the submit button from the keyboard is pressed, you can use [`onSubmitEditing`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onsubmitediting).

```js
<TextInput
  onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
    console.log('Key pressed: ', nativeEvent.key)
  }}
  onSubmitEditing={({ nativeEvent }) => {
    console.log('The submit key has been pressed')

    console.log('OnSubmitEditing: ', {
      text: nativeEvent.text,
      eventCount: nativeEvent.eventCount,
      target: nativeEvent.target
    })
  }}
/>
```

For multiline `TextInput`, you can use the prop [`blurOnSubmit`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#bluronsubmit) as `true` to trigger the onSubmitEditing event instead of inserting a new line into the field.

```js
<TextInput
  onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
    // This code will be run when value of `blurOnSubmit` is `false`
    if (nativeEvent.key === 'Enter') {
      console.log('The Enter key has been pressed')
    }

    console.log('Key pressed: ', nativeEvent.key)
  }}
  onSubmitEditing={({ nativeEvent }) => {
    console.log('The submit key has been pressed')

    console.log('OnSubmitEditing: ', {
      text: nativeEvent.text,
      eventCount: nativeEvent.eventCount,
      target: nativeEvent.target
    })
  }}
  multiline
  blurOnSubmit
/>
```

> Note: When the multiline `TextInput` has the prop `blurOnSubmit` as `false`, the `onKeyPress` will log the native event key value equal to `Enter`.

You can see the complete example in this [Snack Expo](https://snack.expo.dev/@marcelofreires/stackoverflow-questions-76205877) and run it on your device using the [Expo Go App](https://expo.dev/client).

Comment: Great! But I don't see 'OK' key this way. Do you khow how I can to listen 'OK' key?

Comment: I updated the example and added the `onSubmitEditing` usage on the Snack Expo for refer

Comment: It's good way, but unfortunately onSubmitEditing don't work this multiline={true} for Android. And multiline={true} is very important for my app. Apparently i have to write my own keyboard.

Comment: Hey! I have added a multiline example trigging `onSubmitEditing` event and logging the `Enter` key

Comment: I finally got the functionality I need. I am very grateful to you.

Comment: Any time! I'm happy to help you